# Highly variable genes analysis by DESeq2

Tags: rna-seq, deseq2

In the following [article](https://f1000research.com/articles/4-1070/v2). There are two ways of getting highly variable genes:

```
resSig <- subset(res, padj < 0.1)
head(resSig[ order(resSig$log2FoldChange, decreasing=TRUE), ])
```

Getting genes that are statistically significant, then ordering them by the `log2FoldChange` which is

> The column *log2FoldChange* is the effect size estimate. It tells us how much the gene’s expression seems to have changed due to treatment with dexamethasone in comparison to untreated samples.

And the second one:

```
topVarGenes <- head(order(rowVars(assay(rld)),decreasing=TRUE),20)
```

I am struggling to understand what are the differences between the two ways of getting the most variable genes. What is the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first method (`resSig$log2FoldChange`) is for getting the most differentially expressed genes. These are the genes with the biggest differences between specific groups you pre-define.

The second method (`rowVars(assay(rld))`) is for getting the highly variable genes. These are the genes most variable across all samples regardless of which samples they are.